# Some errors have occured when I installed lucene, a perl module!

Tags: perl, make, test

Some errors have occured when I installed lucene, a perl module:

```
[xlwang@localhost Lucene-0.18]$ make test

Running Mkbootstrap for Lucene ()
chmod 644 Lucene.bs
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /home/xlwang/local/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-load.t .. 1/1 
#   Failed test 'use Lucene;'
#   at t/00-load.t line 6.
#     Tried to use 'Lucene'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/home/xlwang/Lucene-0.18/blib/arch/auto/Lucene/Lucene.so' for module Lucene: /usr/lib/../lib64/libclucene.so.0: undefined symbol: pthread_mutexattr_settype at /home/xlwang/local/lib/perl5/5.20.0/x86_64-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
#  at t/00-load.t line 6.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-load.t line 6.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-load.t line 6.
# Testing Lucene 0.18, Perl 5.020000, /home/xlwang/local/bin/perl
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/00-load.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00-load.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.08 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.16 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] error 1
```

My os is Redhat 6.4, and Perl version is 5.20.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Did you install clucene library?

Comment: yes,clucene-core and clucene-core-devel are both installed.[xlwang@localhost amigo]$ rpm -q clucene-core

clucene-core-0.9.21b-1.el6.x86_64
[xlwang@localhost amigo]$ rpm -q clucene-core-devel

clucene-core-devel-0.9.21b-1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Where did you put clucene in? `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`?

Comment: In /usr/lib64. And before I make the module Lucene , I add this path in the makefile.pl. Then, make is all right, but make test occured errors.

Comment: @xiwang0903: It's strange, it's ok in my machine. Do you try install via cpan?

Comment: yes, I tried to install lucene via cpan, but errors occured when it make test. Whether the version of clucene is the problem? What version is your clucene and lucene?

Comment: `clucene-core-2.3.3.4-10.fc20.x86_64` and `Lucene 0.18`.

Comment: My clucene which comes with the os is 0.9.21b. And I tried to install clucene 2.3.3.4 in another user.

Comment: The error message indicates the problem comes from libclucene.so.0 (from the redhat package), not the perl module itself. It seems it was not compiled with `-pthread` as it should have.